# Are limits of integration defined with respect to the pronumeral or the differential?

Tags: definite-integrals

Consider the indefinite integral $$\int x^2 \,d(x^2).$$ It evaluates fairly easily to $\tfrac{x^4}{2} + C$. My question is about what happens when we start evaluating definite integrals with respect to these functions. In a specific example, how would $\displaystyle \int_0^2 x^2 \,d(x^2)$ be evaluated?
Would it be: $$\int_0^2 x^2 \,d(x^2)=\left[\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(x^2\right)^2\right]_0^2 =\frac{4}{2}-0=2 $$ with the limits applying to $x^2$, or would it be: $$\int_0^2 x^2 \,d(x^2)=\left[\frac{1}{2}\cdot x^4\right]_0^2 =\frac{16}{2}-0=8 $$ with the limits applying to $x$.

Hope someone can clarify, thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your $d(x^2)$ the differential of a Stieljes Integral?

Comment: Or did you just pull one $x$ into the integral and left the other one at the differential :)?

Comment: Hi @vitamind! Good questions, and thank you for your help. I honestly don't know, but I think the Stieltjes Integral is the right. path to go down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Confusion**

If this is a Riemann integral I think I have to disappoint you. I don't think there is something like
$$\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}g(x) = \int_a^b f(x)\,\frac{g(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$
It just does not make sense to define something like that. What is the problem with the integral on the right hand side? Why do we need a new notation? If there is, I take everything back. But it is not widely known, you should have defined it.

**A similar integral**

In fact there is a well-defined integral that looks like yours. It's called the Stieltjes integral, a generic term for the Riemann-Stieltjes integral and the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral.
$$\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}g(x).$$
You may look up it's definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral). I will not go into detail but it has a nice property if $g(x)$ is absolutely continous
$$\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}g(x) = \int_a^b f(x)g'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

**Stieltjes integral of your problem**

In your example take $f(x)=g(x)=x^2$. Since $g(x) = x^2$ is absolutely continous we can write
$$\int_0^2 x^2\,\mathrm{d}x^2 = 2\int_0^2 x^3\,\mathrm{d}x=\left[\frac{x^4}{2}\right]_{0}^{2} = 8.$$

Comment: There are two "t"s in "Stieltjes".

Comment: Oh yes, Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! I suppose I am looking at a Stieltjes integral, and that means that the $a$ and $b$ refer to values of $x$, not values of $g(x)$.

Comment: @L.Coy If my answer has helped you, I'd appreciate a green checkmark.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to interpret $I= \int_0^2 x^2 \,d(x^2):$
$$I=\int_0^2 x^2 2x\,dx={{2x^4}\over 4}\big|_0^2=8$$
and, substituting $u=x^2,$
$$I=\int_0^4 u\,du={u^2\over 2}\big|_0^4=8.$$

Comment: So you're just writing my answer in a different form?

Comment: Right—so the $0$ and $2$ unambiguously are values of $x$, not values of $x^2$?